# Entity Framework 6: map complex type to multiple columns

Tags: entity-framework

I have a problem with Entity Framework (6, not Core). I already tried several things and googled around but I can't figure it out so I'm asking here.

Thats my db-scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE MyItem
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [Start] date NOT NULL,
    [End] date NOT NULL
)
```

And these are my classes:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyTimespan IsValidTimespan { get; set; }
}

public class MyTimespan
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map

- the value from "MyItem.IsValidTimespan.Start" to the "Start"-column
- the value from "MyItem.IsValidTimespan.Ende" to the "Ende"-column

I already tried different things with Attributes on the MyTimespan-class ("ComplexType" and "Column" Attributes) and also some hacks with the modelBuilder, nothing worked.

How can I get this to work?

Thank you and best regards,
Alex

Comment: Read this [article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. The code I posted above is not 100% correct: the properties of MyTimespan did not had setters. The following changes in "MyTimespan" did it:

1. adding the annotations mentioned in my question
2. adding private setters to the properties
3. adding a private default constructor